# Frequency of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame indexed with a date (Python datetime object). How could I find the frequency as the number of months of data in the data frame?

I tried the attribute `data_frame.index.freq`, but it returns a none value. I also tried `asfreq` function using `data_frame.asfreq('M',how={'start','end'}` but it does not return the expected results. Please advise how I can get the expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to convert you index of datetimes to a DatetimeIndex, the easiest way is to use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Now you can do timeseries/frame operations, like [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or TimeGrouper.

*If your data has a consistent frequency, then this will be `df.index.freq`, if it doesn't (e.g. if some days are missing) then `df.index.freq` will be None.*

Comment: Thanks your tip was useful. I think there is some missing data.

Comment: I find the idiom `assert(isinstance(df.index.freq, pd.pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.Day))` essential when moving around lots of data that is resampled.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to be use pandas Timestamp for your index instead of datetime to use 'freq'. See example below

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2012-1-1','2012-2-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
print (df.index.freq)
```

yields,

```
<Day>
```

You can easily convert your dataframe like so,

```
df.index = [pd.Timestamp(d) for d in df.index]
```