# How to choose the correct arguments of statsmodels STL function?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've been reading about time-series decomposition, and have a fairly good idea of how it works on simple examples, but am having trouble extending the concepts.

For example, some simple synthetic data I'm playing with:

[image]

So there is no actual time associated with this data. It could be sampled every second or every year. Whatever the sampling frequency, the period is roughly 160 time steps, and using this as the `period` argument yields the expected results:

```
# seasonal=13 based on example in the statsmodels user guide
decomp = STL(synth.value, period=160, seasonal=13).fit()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(12,6))
decomp.trend.plot(title='Trend', ax=ax[0])
decomp.seasonal.plot(title='Seasonal', ax=ax[1])
decomp.resid.plot(title='Residual', ax=ax[2])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But looking at other datasets, it's not really that easy to see the period of the seasonality, so it leads me to a couple of questions:

How do you find the correct arguments in real-world messy data, particularly the `period` argument but also the others too? Is it just a parameter search that you perform until the decomposition looks sane?

> #### Parameters
>
> **endog** : array_like
> Data to be decomposed. Must be squeezable to 1-d.
>
> **period** : Periodicity of the sequence. If None and endog is a pandas Series or DataFrame, attempts to determine from endog. If endog is a ndarray,
> period must be provided.
>
> **seasonal** : Length of the seasonal smoother. Must be an odd integer, and should
> normally be >= 7 (default).
>
> **trend** :  Length of the trend smoother. Must be an odd integer. If not provided
> uses the smallest odd integer greater than 1.5 * period / (1 - 1.5 /
> seasonal), following the suggestion in the original implementation.

Comment: Same question with you. If I only have 1 or 2 years time series at daily freqency, I really  dont know how to clarify `period` parameter...

Comment: [The official guide almost have nothing about parameters](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question. After tracing some of their codebase, I have found the following. This may help:

- Statsmodels expects a `DatetimeIndex`'d DataFrame.
- This `DatetimeIndex` can have a frequency. You can either [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) your data with Pandas, or explicitly set a frequency in your index. You can check `df.index`, look for the `freq` attribute.

This leads to two situations:

### Your index has frequency set

If you have set a frequency in your index, statsmodels will inherit this frequency and automatically use this to determine a `period`.
It makes use of the `freq_to_period` method internally, defined [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py#L776) in the tsatools submodule.

To summarise what this does: *The period is the expected periodicity of your seasonal component, translated back to a year.*.

In other words: "how often your seasonal cycle will repeat itself in a year".
For reference, read the note on the `freq_to_period` method definition:
`Annual maps to 1, quarterly maps to 4, monthly to 12, weekly to 52.`

This is both done for the method `seasonal_decompose` [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py#L156), as well as for `STL` [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/_stl.pyx#L220).

### Your index has **no** frequency set

It gets a bit more complicated if your data does not have a `freq` attribute set.
The `seasonal_decompose` checks whether it can find an `inferred_freq` attribute of your index set [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py#L140), STL takes the same approach [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/_stl.pyx#L217).

This `inferred_freq` was set using the pandas function `infer_freq`, which is defined in the Pandas package [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8e0baa2360a998f76a8e70dbee7bbf7339caf501/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py#L130), to *Infer the most likely frequency given the input index.*. Pandas automatically gives a DataFrame with a `DatetimeIndex` an `index.inferred_freq` attribute by default, if you have at least 3 elements.

**TLDR**: The `period` parameter should be set to the amount of times you expect the seasonal cycle to re-occur within a year. You can explicitly set this, or otherwise statsmodels will automatically infer this from the `freq` attribute of your datetimeindex. If the `freq` attribute is `None`, it will depend on Pandas' `index.inferred_freq` attribute to determine the frequency, and then convert this to pre-set periodicity.

Comment: my input to `endog` is a `pandas.Series` with continuous values as inputs with `DataTimeIndex` as index of type `Timestamp` with `%Y-%m-%d` format and are of yearly frequency. When I passed that as input, I got `ValueError: period must be a positive integer >= 2` error. Setting `period` to 1, still gave me that error. Since your answer mentions that "yearly maps to 1", is setting `period` to 2 correct?

Comment: I would expect your code to run correctly with the `period` set to 1 indeed. However, I see that the ValueError is indeed raised in STL [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/_stl.pyx#L221). 

Does the input data already has a frequency set on its index?
You could try to set the frequency of your index to a yearly value (`.as_freq('Y')` - note that this [used to be](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#period-aliases) 'A' prior to pandas 2.2.0).

I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017052/decompose-for-time-series-valueerror-you-must-specify-a-period-or-x-must-be)