# Understanding period parameter in statsmodel.tsa.seasonal

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

So I am new to Time Series analysis, and want to check my data for seasonality and trend.
I tried using both [`STL`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html) and [`seasonal_decompose`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) from `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal` module.
My question is regarding an input parameter, in both cases called `period` and described as:

> Periodicity of the sequence

for `STL` case and

> Period of the series

for `seasonal_decompose`.

However, for what I understood they are different.
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350791/5931672), the `STL` `period` parameter is defined as the expected seasonality of my series, for a daily periodicity for example (which is my case) it would be 365.

However, for `seasonal_decompose` I understand is the total number of samples regardless the time resolution. For example, if I have samples taken every hour, it would be `24` for my example case.

This was my conclusion based on the error I got when using `seasonal_decompose` with `period=365` on a timeseries of 6 days, for which I got:

```
ValueError: x must have 2 complete cycles requires 730 observations. x only has 238 observation(s)
```

**Are they indeed different? Did I correctly understood both cases?** And if I understood correctly. Would this imply that `seasonal_decompose` cannot work for uneavenly spaced samples (in my case the samples are taken at a samewhat random date and time so the `STL` parameter adapts much better. Is there a workaround for `seasonal_decompose` on non-evenly distributed samples?

---

The more I read the less I understand. [This](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py#L776) code matches the sampling frequency to the period parameter. From the code docstring:

> Annual maps to 1, quarterly maps to 4, monthly to 12, weekly to 52.

Then it seems a map from sampling frequency `freq` to in integer which means samples per year. So far so good until we see that it does:

```
elif freq == "D":
        return 7
elif freq == "H":
        return 24
```

So for a day it maps to a week frequency and for hours it maps to a day!

Please give me a hand here! I am compleately lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally undestood, period could be defined as:

*Expected samples in a full cycle / repetition of the seasonality component.*

Basically you can just look at your time-series and see the time it takes to repeat itself, and then get the number of samples within that timeframe.

For the [function](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/581119c64e43b6021bf247aa300b13abdfd5ef3b/statsmodels/tsa/tsatools.py#L776) that casts `freq` to period, it just "assumes" that if you have hourly frequency it will repeat it sequence again daily, if you have a frequency sampling of days it will repeat itself in a week and if it's more that that it will have a yearly seasonality.