# Setting time frequency makes dataframe's values all null

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to decompose a time series using sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose() and I got a

```
ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a >DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None
```

I followed the suggestions of the answer here:
[decompose() for time series: ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017052/decompose-for-time-series-valueerror-you-must-specify-a-period-or-x-must-be)

So I tried setting the frequency of my time to minutes since this was the frequency with which the data was recorded.
To that end, I tried the following code:

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('T')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Where 'T' specifies that the frequency is in minutes.  But this resulted in my dataframe having only null values.   How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

so your code might be a little off. Would this work

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
```

Could you share and print out the results of this?

Comment: Turns out that some of the timestamps were never included but they were not represented in the dataframe as NaNs, rather the dataframe skipped that time all together.  So when I incremented by minutes this added rows with NaN values and messed things up.  I believe it's working now but I need to debug a bit more.  If I find further issues, I'll bring it up.... or thank you and close this out.